# IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position

Tags: android, progress-bar, android-recyclerview

[image]

I have a recylerview that have items (containing circle progress bar for survey time left)

I use background thread to update the `CircularProgress bar` to time left

When I scroll my `Recyclerview` I get **java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Inconsistency detected. Invalid item position 26(offset:26).state:30**

MeetingSurveryAdapter.java

```
public class MeetingSurveryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MeetingSurveryAdapter.SurveyViewHolder> {

        private static final String TAG = "SurveryAdapter";

        private List<MeetingSurveyModel> list;
        MeetingSurveyModel model;
        private Context mContext;
        private int mSize;
        private UtilMethods utilMethods;
        private AppCompatActivity activity;

        private int mPreviousPosition;

        // Adapters
        private ArrayAdapter<String> adapterCountry;

        private final List<SurveyViewHolder> lstHolders;

        private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
        private Runnable updateRemainingTimeRunnable = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                        synchronized (lstHolders) {
                                long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                                for (SurveyViewHolder holder : lstHolders) {
                                        holder.updateTimeRemaining(currentTime);
                                }
                        }
                }
        };


        public MeetingSurveryAdapter(Context mContext, List<MeetingSurveyModel> list) {
                this.list = list;
                this.mContext = mContext;
                this.activity = (AppCompatActivity) mContext;
                utilMethods = new UtilMethods(mContext);
                lstHolders = new ArrayList<>();
                startUpdateTimer();
        }

        @Override
        public SurveyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

                View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_meeting_survey, viewGroup, false);
                SurveyViewHolder viewHolder = new SurveyViewHolder(view);
                return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final SurveyViewHolder surveyViewHolder, final int position) {

                model = list.get(position);
                surveyViewHolder.tvTitle.setText(model.Title);
                surveyViewHolder.tvDate.setText(utilMethods.formatDateMeetingSurvey(model.MeetingDate));
                surveyViewHolder.tvParticipantsCount.setText("Participants: " + model.Participants);

                surveyViewHolder.setData(list.get(position));
                synchronized (lstHolders) {
                        lstHolders.add(surveyViewHolder);
                }
                surveyViewHolder.updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());

                surveyViewHolder.relativeTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                                openMettingSurveyList(surveyViewHolder, position);
                        }
                });
                if (position > mPreviousPosition) {
                        animate1(surveyViewHolder, true);
                } else {
                        animate1(surveyViewHolder, false);
                }
                mPreviousPosition = position;
        }

        private void openMettingSurveyList(SurveyViewHolder surveyViewHolder, int position) {
                MeetingSurveyModel model = list.get(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, NewActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra(QrgSensContants.EMP_SURVEY_ID, model.ManualSurvey_Id);
                activity.startActivity(intent);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
                return list.size();
        }

        public class SurveyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
                @Bind(R.id.relative_title)
                RelativeLayout relativeTitle;
                @Bind(R.id.img_number3)
                ImageView imgNumber3;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_title)
                TextView tvTitle;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_date)
                TextView tvDate;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_participants_count)
                TextView tvParticipantsCount;
                @Bind(R.id.prg_counter)
                DonutProgress prgCounter;
                @Bind(R.id.tv_counter)
                TextView tvCounter;

                public void setData(MeetingSurveyModel item) {
                        model = item;
                        prgCounter.setSuffixText("");
                        updateTimeRemaining(System.currentTimeMillis());
                }

                public void updateTimeRemaining(long currentTime) {
                        long timeDiff = utilMethods.getLongDate(model.MeetingDeadLine) - currentTime;
                        if (timeDiff > 0) {
                                //int minutes= Integer.parseInt(String.format("%d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(timeDiff) ));
                                int minutes = (int) ((timeDiff / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
                                prgCounter.setProgress(minutes);
                                //prgCounter.setSuffixText(""+minutes);
                        } else {
                                list.remove(getLayoutPosition());
                                //notifyItemRemoved(getLayoutPosition());
                                tvCounter.setText("Expired!!");
                                //prgCounter.setSuffixText("0");
                        }
                }

                public SurveyViewHolder(View itemView) {
                        super(itemView);
                        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
                        prgCounter.setTextSize(18);
                        prgCounter.setTextColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
                }

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                        switch (view.getId()) {
                        }
                }
        }

        private void startUpdateTimer() {
                Timer tmr = new Timer();
                tmr.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                                mHandler.post(updateRemainingTimeRunnable);
                        }
                }, 0, 60000);
        }

        public void animate1(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, boolean goesDown) {
                int holderHeight = holder.itemView.getHeight();
                holder.itemView.setPivotY(goesDown == true ? 0 : holderHeight);

                AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
                ObjectAnimator animatorTranslateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, "translationY", goesDown == true ? 200 : 0, 0);
                animatorTranslateY.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());

                animatorTranslateY.setDuration(700);
                animatorTranslateY.start();
        }
}
```

Comment: this seems to be a kind of bug or not a real bug but buggy :) ....see here, https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77232

Comment: I have the same Error its coming because I've use endless recycler as my data get to the last position it doesn't get the item count like if you set it get 27 item count in every scroll at last may be you don't get 27 items so its occur then after that as i get whats the problem just created logic that if I mod(%) list.size() by item i'm getting if it equal to 0 just use notifyItemrangeInserted otherwise notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Dude i was manipulating my list data . Because of that its size got increased . That created the problem